# React-native 0.50.4 iOS crush on launch in release mode (help to define the problem)

Tags: ios, react-native, crash-reports

I'm facing an issue with my react-native app release build. Everything was ok until it started crashing in release mode. How can I read and understand my crash log?

Here comes the full log with stack trace: https://pastebin.com/3ry9bfid

```
Incident Identifier: 03FD209B-05E4-485F-9FAE-8935F32160E0
CrashReporter Key:   e64d495312d6ff70181d76e23d965aa029dc9539
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             BINOMysteryShopper [4845]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/778CFE6F-9E8F-4458-AAA5-E4A8D1390222/BINOMysteryShopper.app/BINOMysteryShopper
Identifier:          com.getbino.BINOMysteryShopper
Version:             1 (2.0.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.getbino.BINOMysteryShopper [1316]


Date/Time:           2018-12-27 15:45:54.7568 +0400
Launch Time:         2018-12-27 15:45:54.0464 +0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)
Baseband Version:    3.01.06
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Maybe a list of installed libs will help somehow:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "4.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.8.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "haul": "^1.0.0-beta.13",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.19.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-intl": "2.4.0",
    "react-intl-po": "2.1.1",
    "react-moment-proptypes": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.4",
    "react-native-audio": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-charts-wrapper": "0.4.1",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "1.0.3",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.2",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "0.10.8",
    "react-native-fs": "2.9.10",
    "react-native-geocoder": "0.5.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.19.2",
    "react-native-inview": "1.1.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.4.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.20.1",
    "react-native-maps-super-cluster": "git+https://github.com/Ble3k/react-native-maps-super-cluster.git",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-slowlog": "1.0.2",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.10.9",
    "react-native-spinkit": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "5.5.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.5.13",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "reduce-reducers": "0.1.2",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-batched-actions": "0.1.6",
    "redux-restify": "git+https://gitlab.getbino.com/Q-CIS-OPEN/redux-restify.git",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "reselect": "3.0.1",
    "semver": "5.4.1",
    "uuid": "3.1.0",
    "webpack": "2.7.0"
  },
```

Comment: Can you put the code for the start screen of your app?

Comment: Hi, do you mean the code of entry index.js ? This is my entry index.js code https://pastebin.com/WPsEG7M0. And this is my RootComp index.js code https://pastebin.com/cDWmRiZ0. Did some of this help ?

Answer (score 0):

So, If someone is facing the same issue - it was haul@***1.0.0-beta.13*** https://github.com/callstack/haul. Version ***1.0.0-beta.10*** resolved the issue.